# Why stored procedure out parameter is not getting read by entity framework's ExecuteSqlCommand method?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to read the OUT parameters value returned by stored procedure but it throws error **DBNULL**. Even the procedure is returning the value.

Code:

```
   int? outParam= 0;

   SqlParameter sqlParam= new SqlParameter("@model", user.Name+" Model");
   SqlParameter sqlParamOut = new SqlParameter("out", outParam);
   sqlParamOut.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
   sqlParamOut.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

   UsersPhonesDBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.InsertPhones @model, @out", sqlParam, sqlParamOut);

   outParam = Convert.ToInt32(sqlParamOut.Value);
```

SP:

```
alter PROCEDURE InsertPhones (

    @model varchar(100),
    @out int output
)
AS
BEGIN
        Insert into Phones (Model, Manufacturer)
        Values 
        (
            @model,
            'Hunain Phone'
        )

        set @out= SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        Select @out
END
GO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That sp code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh: sql server 2014

Answer (score 3):

`out` parameters in SQL Server are fun. You have to repeat yourself *everywhere*.

Specifically, here, you've forgotten to mention it in the parameter list when calling the stored proc. `dbo.InsertPhones @model, @out` should be `dbo.InsertPhones @model, @out out`. There may also be a way to omit the parameter list from this string and instruct SQL Server that you're giving it a stored procedure name, not arbitrary query text, but I'm not sure how you would do that specifically here (with an `SqlCommand` object, it would be via the `CommandType` property).

If you're using an `out` parameter, the `select` at the end of the stored procedure is unnecessary, but I assume that was an attempt at a fix.

Comment: with love, it worked. Thanks a ton and I believe the Microsoft is tremendous at sucking programmer's energy, this could've been put in an easy way but no. Anyways, thanks again.